# React-Table not loading API data with server-side options enabled

Tags: reactjs, axios, server-side, react-table

I am using react-table version 6.9.2 to connect to an API and display the data. My initial implementation worked fine:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
        .get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
            responseType: 'json'
        })
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ posts: response.data });
        });
}
return (
        <ReactTable
            columns={columns}
            data={this.state.posts}
            filterable
            defaultPageSize={5}
            noDataText={'Loading...'}
        />
    );
```

However I want to scale up my application and connect to a database and enable server side pagination. I followed the example provided:
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#server-side-data

However the data is not being displayed when I implemented the below changes to my ReactTable

```
<ReactTable
        columns={columns}
        data={this.state.posts}
        pages={this.state.pages}
        loading={this.state.loading}
        filterable
        defaultPageSize={5}
        noDataText={"Loading..."}
        manual // informs React Table that you'll be handling sorting and pagination server-side
        onFetchData={(state, instance) => {
          // show the loading overlay
          this.setState({ loading: true });
          // fetch your data
          axios
            .post("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
              page: state.page,
              pageSize: state.pageSize,
              sorted: state.sorted,
              filtered: state.filtered
            })
            .then(res => {
              // Update react-table
              this.setState({
                posts: res.data,
                data: res.data.posts,
                pages: res.data.pages,
                loading: false
              });
            });
        }}
      />
```

I believe I am messing up with the onFetchData function but I am not entirely sure as to what. Is there a better way to enable this? Any help would be appreciated!

I've got a working code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yp88v0kx2z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please make few corrections in urls,callback and axios

https://codesandbox.io/s/lrn7j5vjrl?fontsize=14

Comment: Ah, I see I messed up with the GET & POST method! I can see the data but the options for react-table aren't working such as displaying 5 rows per page using the defaultPageSize={5} option. Can you take a look?

One of the examples had a asynch table mockup which shows the functionality I want to achieve but I am a bit lost with the setup...
: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-server-side-data

Comment: @jsnoobie post request is not giving any data. Can you be particular about the request url and paramters.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant I understood from your changes that my previous implementation for getting data was incorrect due to the wrong request type; this is something you've fixed in your sandbox which works great!

The current issue I have is with the options to customize the react-table. For example when you use defaultPageSize={5}, this shows only 5 rows per page & gets loaded dynamically as you click through(seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-server-side-data) In your demo it loads all rows instead of 5

Comment: can you check sandbox now, do changes based on your requirements https://codesandbox.io/s/lrn7j5vjrl.

Comment: Unfortunately there is still no difference. Not sure what changes have been made but on App load all 100 rows are still being loaded instead of 5 rows. The defaultPageSize={5} option is not being applied, which is the one being used to set how many rows should appear in the page at any time.

Comment: sorry for the wrong URL. i accidentally forgot to share updated URL. please refer https://codesandbox.io/s/lrn7j5vjrl?fontsize=14. pagination works fine

Comment: Seems a bit hacky. If you check in the network tab, all 100 rows are still being rendered on the browser with each page which isn't optimal...however your initial answer helped solve my data issue which was the main question so this is acceptable, thank you :) 

Will look into optimizing this more and explore this other issue.

Cheers.

Comment: so in short we are deceiving on the front end and fetching all data in one go, I mean is pagination not suppose to call api on each row size change ?